# ThreeJS- Adding bloom pass affects canvas transparency

Tags: javascript, three.js

**BLOOM AFFECTS TRANSPARENCY**

For renderer I'm having this setup:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, preserveDrawingBuffer:true, alpha:true } );
```

for bloom pass (post processing)

```
var renderPass = new RenderPass( scene, camera );
var bloomPass = new UnrealBloomPass( new THREE.Vector2( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight ), 1.5, 0.4, 0.85 );
bloomPass.exposure =0.2;
bloomPass.threshold =0;
bloomPass.strength = 0.2;
bloomPass.radius = 0.1;
composer.addPass( renderPass );
composer.addPass( bloomPass );
```

and while rendering I'm using

```
composer.render()
```

but this is **affecting the transparency of the canvas by darkening it** (Scene)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, your code is right for the creation of the `UnrealBloomPass`, but the issue is in the shader of the `UnrealBloomPass` at the method **`getSeperableBlurMaterial`**.

You need to replace the **`fragmentShader`** by this code below and your pass background will consider the alpha channel:

```
fragmentShader:
    "#include <common>\
    varying vec2 vUv;\n\
    uniform sampler2D colorTexture;\n\
    uniform vec2 texSize;\
    uniform vec2 direction;\
    \
    float gaussianPdf(in float x, in float sigma) {\
        return 0.39894 * exp( -0.5 * x * x/( sigma * sigma))/sigma;\
    }\
    void main() {\n\
          vec2 invSize = 1.0 / texSize;\
          float fSigma = float(SIGMA);\
          float weightSum = gaussianPdf(0.0, fSigma);\
          float alphaSum = 0.0;\
          vec3 diffuseSum = texture2D( colorTexture, vUv).rgb * weightSum;\
          for( int i = 1; i < KERNEL_RADIUS; i ++ ) {\
            float x = float(i);\
            float w = gaussianPdf(x, fSigma);\
            vec2 uvOffset = direction * invSize * x;\
            vec4 sample1 = texture2D( colorTexture, vUv + uvOffset);\
            vec4 sample2 = texture2D( colorTexture, vUv - uvOffset);\
            diffuseSum += (sample1.rgb + sample2.rgb) * w;\
            alphaSum += (sample1.a + sample2.a) * w;\
            weightSum += 2.0 * w;\
          }\
          gl_FragColor = vec4(diffuseSum/weightSum, alphaSum/weightSum);\n\
    }"
```

Answer (score 0):

A bloom pass is doing some mix between the image and a blurred version, causing colors to change. You should consider setting the [WebGLRenderer tone mapping property](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.toneMapping) to set a good color dynamic range

Tone mapping definition ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_mapping))

> Tone mapping is a technique used in image processing and computer
>   graphics to map one set of colors to another to approximate the
>   appearance of high dynamic range images in a medium that has a more
>   limited dynamic range.

Add this line in your init routine

```
renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ReinhardToneMapping
```

Comment: No success, I've also tired using other tone mappings like     "ACESFilmicToneMapping"

Comment: First remark, bloomPass.exposure is useless, there is no exposure param in UnrealBloomPass code https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/postprocessing/UnrealBloomPass.js

Comment: Try keeping threshold = 0 and radius = 0 and increase the strength param to see how it affects your rendering. You can also try to increase renderer.toneMappingExposure as tonemapping has changed the dynamic range of the color rendering

Comment: No Success, Getting back the transparency at the cost of bloom :( Bloom effect is very subtle.

Comment: Maybe you can share some screen of your scene? It could be useful to help you